# WiFi "device not ready" but `iwlist scan` works

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

Running Ubuntu 20.04 on a ASUS ZenBook.

I installed the routine system updates and suddenly the WiFi dropdown says "device not ready". Strangely though, if I run `iwlist wlan0 scan` it correctly lists available WiFi networks.

A bit of info:

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 30
       serial: 38:00:25:4b:a5:37
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-34-generic firmware=46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:b431c000-b431ffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 66:9e:5d:31:63:5f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.11.0-34-generic firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.71.84 link=yes multicast=yes
...
```

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.374876] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.383293] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
[    2.383296] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    2.383297] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    2.383299] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    2.383300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    2.383301] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    2.383302] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    2.383304] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    2.383305] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    2.383306] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    2.383307] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    2.383309] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    2.383310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    2.383311] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    2.383312] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
[    2.383314] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
[    2.383315] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 28
[    2.383513] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.747691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x318
[    2.795863] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 38:00:25:4b:a5:37
[    2.863515] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
```

I've been a happy Ubuntu user since 2007 and this computer has been working fine for the last 3 years. Any help would be much appreciated!